# Enqueue scripts to footer

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

i know how i can print a single script with wp_dequeue_script and wp_enqueue_script to the footer:

```
function dequeue_my_scripts() {
 wp_dequeue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script');
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_my_scripts', 11 );

function enqueue_scripts_to_footer() {
   wp_enqueue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script');
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'enqueue_scripts_to_footer' );
```

But how can i print a couple of scripts to the footer. Is there a posibility to use enumeration for example:

```
function dequeue_my_scripts() {
 wp_dequeue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script','next-handle-script',        'next-handle-script'.....);
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_my_scripts', 11 );

function enqueue_scripts_to_footer() {
   wp_enqueue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script','next-handle-script',     'next-handle-script'.....);
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'enqueue_scripts_to_footer' );
```

Or is there another possibility??

Comment: What is wrong in calling `wp_enqueue_script` multiple times with different arguments (links to different scripts) in `enqueue_scripts_to_footer` ?

Comment: ok, so i can use: `function enqueue_scripts_to_footer() {
   wp_enqueue_script('onother-script');
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'enqueue_scripts_to_footer' );`   But i have to change the function name: `enqueue_scripts_to_footer()` right? or can i use the name two times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this:-

```
function dequeue_my_scripts() {
   wp_dequeue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script');
   wp_dequeue_script('next-handle-script');
   wp_dequeue_script('next-handle-script-2');
   /* and so on*/
}
add_action( 'wp_print_scripts', 'dequeue_my_scripts', 11 );

function enqueue_scripts_to_footer() {
   wp_enqueue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script');
   wp_enqueue_script('next-handle-script');
   wp_enqueue_script('next-handle-script-2');
   /* and so on */
}
add_action( 'wp_footer', 'enqueue_scripts_to_footer' );
```

What's wrong in this implementation?

**EDIT:**

I would also like to notify you that this is the correct implementation of what you are trying to achieve:-

```
function enqueue_scripts_to_footer() {
   wp_enqueue_script('dgx_donate_paypalstd_script', false, array(), false, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('next-handle-script', false, array(), false, true);
   wp_enqueue_script('next-handle-script-2', false, array(), false, true);
   /* and so on */
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_scripts_to_footer' );
```

Comment: Little addendum: for the 4th {version number} parameter, it can take `false` and `null` as well. Don't know which is better or more elegant. Or if it's there any difference. I use null, but false seems legit as well. Anyone opinion, pro-s ,con-s on this?

Answer (score 0):

Right out of the codex:  the fifth argument to the wp_enqueue_script function call is a boolean to tell it whether or not to put the script in the footer:

https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script

Comment: yeah i know the boolean..but what is with my example above. Can i use more than one Handler for the function wp_dequeue_script?

Comment: That's not the question you asked.  And no, the call to wp_dequeue_script expects a string.  Put your calls to it in a foreach loop if you want to dequeue multiple handles...